# Duplicate output keys

Tags: blockchain, transaction-data

Output keys are 256 bits public keys. They should be unique.

Are there any duplicate output keys ?

What happens if there is any ? Is it a double spend ?

Answer (score 5):

Here are the duplicates for block in range(1,1500000), with the count:

- **8837** 9b2e4c0281c0b02e7c53291a94d1d0cbff8883f8024f5142ee494ffbbd088071
- **70** 2a74a3c4c36d32e95633d44ba9a7b8188297b2ac91afecab826b86fabaa70916
- **8** 362da94d535b602c1ea909627da4ffb35bf01dd4689698f6393f3a5e995973b8
- **7** 0ad4bab9288ecbb1066ece2ea3fba29a013301cfa1d472da7467876635996a34
- **6** 71420acc3b5e7b3aa5405fdf06cc435c37339f8efd08c7033c4a000e0d4804b7
- **6** ad0f4a8bb1849166d5e75c46f52b8390629f093cf100f8221f9de8f00f00f80a
- **5** 944e84a00c2e47b8ab6c1ed4e7d5325449940bd7d9947c321f2f78c6f67266cc
- **5** 52d128bc9913d5ee8b702c37609917c2357b2f587e5de5622348a3acd718e5d6
- **4** 88883ef499326c4344935c57f088758e1370a80ab757d45e0e09413485542f3b
- **3** 21242bd2219db8651fbd553339fae003d05b1c01b20424554725bd8e7834ad11
- **3** 42e782ea6c9b43d2fc101bf31db45847e2a99f91b596db1afe4851b63bdfa7d6
- **3** b8ed916c56b3a99c9cdf22c7be7ec4e85587e5d40bc46bf6995313c288ad841e
- **3** a6f70eae9db3e3a06000fc2cbf38d48f236d289b9ca3673e4a6edb5719e970e2
- **2** 8d820398c912ca0916e964990fd4a34ab5cda3d4f8ad992dc12fc7ee63cfa0f0
- **2** 142076b705ec912288816f0a08da20b64f9907bf99fbce74e39a85a300658191
- **2** 7e69fc5c12439bc793ec53993207ea5594ab64e2d148cb81f465c3d88f905b87
- **2** 5d397b2a3cb2788a1de2be6632fa2e389b885e59f531d11c51470ae12240f86a
- **2** 1b452b4ac6c6419e06181f8c9f0734bd5bb132d8b75b44bbcd07dd8f553acba6
- **2** c574420256922b0783196e42c98156814e61d9ffa87c1262089be1d42e5f0d27
- **2** b10ba13e303cbe9abf7d5d44f1d417727abcc14903a74e071abd652ce1bf76dd

As noted in [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4h7vy9/should_outputs_public_keys_be_unique_or_not/), the first key (used 8837 times) is also the output key of the coinbase transaction in the genesis block.

Quoting smooth:

> No its not a double spend. It is burning coins, so in a sense the
>   opposite of a double spend. Possibly unintended due to a bug, but
>   without knowing who is generating those or why it is impossible to
>   say.

Each key can only be spent once, so out of these 8950 outputs, 8930 are unspendable.

Comment: Related question, which might be of interest to the reader: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4163/can-a-one-time-public-key-be-used-for-more-than-one-payment/4169#4169

Answer (score 3):

As I've recently stumbled over this issue as well, here's a CSV file that contains all reused pubkeys and their count: [reused_pubk.csv](https://github.com/oerpli/MONitERO/blob/master/csv/reused_pubk.csv)

And here also the blocks and transactions where and when they occur (Timestamp, Block, TX Hash): [reused_pubk_full.csv](https://github.com/oerpli/MONitERO/blob/master/csv/reused_pubk_full.csv)

(Both links go to a github repo, if changes occur at some point, use [this commit](https://github.com/oerpli/MONitERO/commit/4f23d02354bd101a564dc6aa7e95d7cfceb103ea))

It seems that whatever bug was responsible for it has been patched at some time after 2016-10-23 (or the last client updated his wallet software back then).